# How To Implement simple delete(with red minus button) in UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I'm deleting cell from table view and it implement swipe delete, following code I'm using:

```
#pragma mark -   
#pragma mark Table View Data Source Methods

- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated
{ 
[super setEditing:editing animated:animated]; 
[addTagTableView setEditing:editing animated:YES];
}

- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{ 
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete; 
}  

 //Updating the data-model array and deleting the row
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tv commitEditingStyle:    (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    // If row is deleted, remove it from the list. 
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) 
    {
            [self.tagsArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [self.addTagTableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }
}
```

This allows me to implement swipe delete, but I want simple minus red button delete, how to achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put UIButton and wire up it to IBAction. In IBAction write  so you will be able to do as per your requirement.

```
 -(IBAction)editTableForDeletingRow
 {
      [addTagTableView setEditing:editing animated:YES];
 }
```

Answer (score 7):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}
```

With this code, there is an edit button in your app. If you press this button, the "red minus" appears automatically :)